# Table view Controller duplicate itself in IOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I try to pass value one table view controller to another view controller but second table view controller duplicate itself it opens twice. Could you help me fix about it i pasted my code here
Here is the first table view controller codes

```
    var dataPassed:String!
    var  cars = [String]()


    var valueToPass:String!
    var passedValue:String!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


      cars = [dataPassed,"Audi","Volkswagen"]

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return cars.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("carCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel!.text = cars[indexPath.row]
    return cell

}

override func tableView(tableView: (UITableView!), didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {


    // Get Cell Label
    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow();
    let currentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as UITableViewCell!;

    valueToPass = currentCell.textLabel!.text
    performSegueWithIdentifier("secondide", sender: self)

}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if (segue.identifier == "secondide") {

        // initialize new view controller and cast it as your view controller
        var viewController = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondTableViewController
        // your new view controller should have property that will store passed value
        viewController.value123 = valueToPass
    }





}
```

Here is the second table view controller codes.

```
var SecondArray=[String]()
var value123:String!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

        SecondArray = ["Kemal","Ekren","Hello"]



    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return SecondArray.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SecondCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

        cell.textLabel!.text = SecondArray[indexPath.row]
        return cell



}
```

}

Comment: `1)` It sounds as if you have a segue in your Storyboard between the first table view and the second tableview. This will cause the segue to trigger twice; once from the automatic segue and then secondly when you call `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:`. If you want to manually call `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` the segue must come from the first view controller and not the table view. `2)` Based on your posted code, you can delete your `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method and just link the two tableview via a segue. `3)` Errors exist in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

Answer (score 2):

It sounds as if you have a segue in your Storyboard created by dragging between the first table view and the second tableview. This will cause the segue to trigger twice; once from the automatic segue and then secondly when you call `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:`.

The way I would write this is to delete your`tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method then alter your `prepareForSegue:sender:` method to be something similar to this:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject? {

    // Find the correct segue
    if (segue.identifier == "secondide") {

        // initialize new view controller and cast it as your view controller
        var viewController = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondTableViewController

        // Find the index path of the selected row
       let selectedIndex = self.tableView.indexPathForCell(sender as UITableViewCell)

        // your new view controller should have property that will store passed value
        viewController.value123 = cars[selectedIndex]
    }
}
```

Then ensure the segue is created by control-dragging from the first table view to the second view controller. This will trigger the segue as soon as someone taps a cell.

You will also no longer need your `var valueToPass:String!` property.